# Criteria Query on Sakila Database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate and Criteria Query. I want to perform operations on sakila database. I want a Criteria query for the following `SQL` query:

```
select c.city, cr.country 
from city c 
left join country cr 
on c.country_id = cr.country_id;
```

Comment: you still have any doubt in my answer?

Comment: CreateAlias() takes only two arguements and they both are strings.

Comment: check the api, it has overloaded methods -- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `OneToMany` `uni-directional mapping` between your `Country` and `City` like this:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Set<City> cities = new HashSet<City>();
}
```

Then you can create `Criteria` query like this:

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Country.class);
    criteria.createAlias("cities","c",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

    // This line removes the duplicate results of root entity - `Country`
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

    List<Country> countries = criteria.list();
```